# Checking Backbone view method called with Jasmine

Tags: backbone.js, jasmine

I have a Backbone application I'm working on where all the functionality is namespaced under `App`. I have a view called `App.LoginView`, and I want to test it with Jasmine, but I'm struggling to get it to work.

This is the code for the test:

```
describe("Test the views", function () {
    'use strict';

    beforeEach(function () {
        // Create DOM element
        $('body').append('<div class="content"></div>');
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        $('div.content').remove();
    });

    // Test the LoginView object was created
    it("tests that the LoginView object exists", function () {
        // Check the view definition exists
        expect(App.LoginView).toBeDefined();

        // Spy on the prototype
        spyOn(App, 'LoginView').andCallThrough();

        // Create the view
        this.LoginView = new App.LoginView();

        // Check the view exists
        expect(this.LoginView).toBeDefined();
        expect(this.LoginView.initialize).toBeDefined();
        expect(this.LoginView.template).toBeDefined();
        expect(this.LoginView.tagName).toBeDefined();
        expect(this.LoginView.render).toBeDefined();

        // Remove it
        this.LoginView.remove();
    });
});
```

It throws the following error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'spyOn(App, 'LoginView').andCallThrough()')
```

I'm using the `grunt-contrib-jasmine` to run the tests and `jasmine-jquery` to add support for jQuery. I have used Jasmine a little bit in the past, but I'm struggling to see where I've gone awry here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution in the end. To get it working, I spied on the `initialize` method of the prototype and changed the syntax for the call through as this changed in Jasmine 2.

```
spyOn(App.LoginView.prototype, 'initialize').and.callThrough();
```

I also dynamically inserted a basic template into the DOM using `jasmine-jquery` as otherwise Underscore complained about the missing template:

```
$('body').append('<script type="text/template" id="login-template"><div class="content-padded"></div></script>');
```